# Why is Android Studio telling me my variable is not initialized?

Tags: android, kotlin, variables

I am trying to change the location of an image, and to do that I need a certain variable, which I initialized at the start of this code. I am able to call the variable multiple times with no problem, expect for the second time I call it, on line 7. The exact error is "Variable 'currentHall' must be initialized." How can I fix this?

```
var currentHall: Hall

for (i in 0..11) {
    if(halls[i].name == locationHall) {
        currentHall = halls[i]
    }
}

if (currentHall.image == "segment_hori.png") {
    youAreHere.y = currentHall.yCoord
    youAreHere.x = currentHall.xCoord + locationCoords
}

if (currentHall.image == "segment_vert.png") {
    youAreHere.y = currentHall.yCoord + locationCoords
    youAreHere.x = currentHall.xCoord
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `currentHall` to be if the `if` condition inside the loop never evaluates to true?

Comment: There is no case where it could not be true, all that is doing is checking which Hall object is the one that should be used based on an input.

Comment: That is knowledge that you have, but the compiler doesn't. All it sees is the code and given that code it would be possible that `currentHall` never gets assigned a value. You can try to "convince" the compiler by e.g.: marking the variable as `lateinit`

Comment: Setting it as lateinit worked, thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create variable in Kotlin without initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52964417/how-to-create-variable-in-kotlin-without-initialization)